# Paraview: single file format for time sequence of stl files?

Tags: surface, paraview

I have time sequence of .stl files of particular geometry. I usually load all the time sequence .stl files in paraview and it works. I would like to know if there is any input file format where one can write all the time sequence geometry data in a single file and load in Paraview instead of having too many files ? I know that one can concatenate .stl files, but then it will be treated as single geometry, not as a sequence.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ParaView supports lots of file formats that supports time sequence.
I would suggest using `pvd` format, wich is a ParaView native format.

Note : there will still be multiple files in a folder, but you will be able to open all files directly by opening the .pvd file.

Comment: That sounds much better than what i do now. Thanks for the answer. Good Day !